# SQL BINARY Operator not showing exact match

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns...

```
[Name] = [Transliteration] = [Hexadecimal] = [HexadecimalUTF8]
```

...with multiple rows of UTF-8 characters, such as:

```
ङ = ṅa = 0919 = e0a499
ञ = ña = 091e = e0a49e
ण = ṇa = 0923 = e0a4a3
न = na = 0928 = e0a4a8
```

In order to search for the row that exactly matches `ña` in the `Transliteration` column , I enter the following command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Samskrta 
WHERE BINARY (Transliteration = concat(0xc3b161)) 
ORDER BY HexadecimalUTF8;
```

...which produces 4 rows.

**Why is the SQL command not producing only the row that exactly matches `ña`?**

**What SQL command produces only the row that exactly matches `ña`?**

The following command produces the same results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Samskrta 
WHERE BINARY (Transliteration = 'ña') 
ORDER BY HexadecimalUTF8;
```

Comment: The column `Transliteration` should be of type `VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin`

Comment: @IVOGELOV: The column `Transliteration` is of type `VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`.

Comment: Using the charset `utf8mb4` and issuing `SET NAMES utf8` before the query, I am receiving only 1 row as a result - `SELECT * FROM Samskrta WHERE Transliteration = 'ña'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIRST OF ALL, your query can't work as indicated: you are applying BINARY() to the result of the logical comparison, NOT comparing the BINARY() of whatever to whatever.

Try reproducing your code PRECISELY if you expect people to be able to tender assistance.